# Approximation degree by trigonometric polynomial

Tags: fourier-series, approximation-theory, trigonometric-series

Let us assume that a real function $f\in C^k(\mathbb R)$ is $2\pi-$periodic. Is it true that, denotig $\Pi_n$ the set of trigonometric polynomials of degree $n$, we have

$$\inf_{g\in \Pi_n} \|f-g\|_\infty = O(n^{-k})?$$

The reason I am asking the question is that a similar result is well known when $\Pi_n$ is instead the class of standard polynomials of degree $n$. I have found some paper which deal with the topic of best approximation by trigonometric polynomials, like [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/best-trigonometric-approximation-fractional-order-derivatives-and-lipschitz-classes/48209B62DD80FDCE5F3127AB95FC23D7), but for what I have understood no such result is present.